# Set TTL Apache Camel JAva DSL

Tags: apache-camel

How do you set the TTL for a message when using Java DSL?

I have something like this:

```
...
from ("timer:something?delay=3000&period=15000")
   ...
   .to("{{some.property}}")
   .end()
...
```

I want to set a time to live on the message being sent.

Comment: the timer component just creates an event, it does not have anything for the life cycle of this event, I thing you want to TTL on some other component, can you specify the component/s that events will be send through

Comment: I left out the logic where the message is created. The message being created is a custom, serializable object sent in an Object Message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting the JMSExpiration header field of the messages being created similar to the following

```
.setHeader("JMSExpiration", constant(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000))
```

We are using Apache ActiveMQ 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

I assume TTL means Time to Live.

In Camel this is component specific how they deal with this. Some components support this, and others do not.

You should check the documentation for the component you use, what it supports.

If you use JMS component then it has the timeToLive option as documented: http://camel.apache.org/jms

And mind about the problem with "client and server clock's can be out of sync". There is some details on the Camel JMS page. Some message brokers has ways to sync the clocks, such as Apache ActiveMQ with its timestamp plugin: http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html