# JMSExpiration vs TimeToLive

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm trying to set message expiration within a Blueprint XML Camel route.  The value I want to set as the expiration is held within the message body (a [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)).

Here's my code:-

```
<setHeader headerName="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY">
    <method bean="NotificationScheduler" method="postponeSending" />
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="JMSExpiration">
    <method bean="NotificationScheduler" method="getExpiry" />
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="ExpirationTest">
    <method bean="NotificationScheduler" method="getExpiry" />
</setHeader>
<to uri="activemq:notifications.splitter" />
```

As you can see from the screen shot below, I'm successfully setting two of the three headers but the setting for "JMSExpiration" (as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507948/set-ttl-apache-camel-java-dsl)) has had no effect.

[image: ActiveMQWeb snippet]

I know I could alternatively use the Recipient List pattern to dynamically set the uri - i.e. pull the expiry out of the message data and append the `?timeToLive=...` option.  However, this seems a little clunky to me.

Is there a way to set expiration via setHeader within the XML?

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your uri to: `activemq:notifications.splitter?preserveMessageQos=true` and you should be fine.

Some JMS headers can be "manually" overriden like you are trying to by using this option.

Please note that you might want to take some precausion, since if you are listening on one JMS endpoint, the arriving messages will have JMS headers populated, and when you send the message out in your "to", the message will keep `JMSDeliveryMode`, `JMSExpiration` and `JMSPriority`. This might or might not be what you want.

Comment: Many thanks - I'm already removing the AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY header in a subsequent route (otherwise every route gets the delay built into it) so will do the same if I need to suppress expriry.