# TimeToLive on Camel response messages

Tags: jms, apache-camel

When using an InOut paradigm to send request/response messages to a JMS endpoint, the [Camel JMS documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) describes how to set a message expiration on the request message, but it doesn't describe whether the response message will have a timeout (JMS expiration) set when it's sent by the consumer of the request message.  The documentation does describe the replyToDeliveryPersistent URI option that the consumer can set to specify that the response message it sends should be non-persistent, but I don't see anything that would let you specify whether the response message will have an expiration date set.

Is there some way to ensure that response messages will be expired (so they can be automatically removed from the broker) if they are unconsumed for a certain amount of time (e.g. because the producer of the request was killed before it read the response to its final request), without implementing a custom ActiveMQ consumer and losing the benefits of using Camel?  I control both the producer and the consumer, so the changes can happen at whichever side they need to be made (and I'm aware that the consumer end is the place this would likely need to be done); the sole criterion here is that Camel must remain the method for processing the message and responding with a reply message, because having to implement that by hand would be worse than living with persistent reply messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to set an expiration time (`JMSExpiration` header) on a message is from its production point (i.e. by the producer).

In your case, the **consumer of your request** should set the `JMSExpiration` date explicitly<sup>1</sup>, using the JMS component's URI option `timeToLive`, and there is no way to set this option from the requesting side.

---

**1)** JMS specification points out that instead of setting the `JMSExpiration` directly, JMS clients should specify the time-to-live. The header is then calculated as the sum of the time-to-live and the current GMT value.

Comment: You're right, the URI option is `replyToDeliveryPersistent`; I've updated the question to fix that.  I'm aware that I'd need to apply this on the consumer's side, and that's no problem since I control both; the `replyToDeliveryPersistent` URI option is also applied on the consumer's URI, so I was expecting to set it there.  I actually explained essentially that in response to another answer, which the author then deleted, so I've updated my question to state that explicitly.

Comment: So I think what you're suggesting is to apply the `JMSExpiration` header (which can in fact be directly sent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507948/set-ttl-apache-camel-java-dsl) to the response message via a Camel processor or directly in the Camel DSL.  That's more cumbersome than I'd have preferred (and I'll probably submit a JIRA for Camel to add a `replyToTimeToLive` URI option to make it easier), but it will work.

Comment: @Tim I'm sorry, but I'm confused now. Let me call the in/out side the **client app** and the other side the **server app**. The *client app* will send a request message and wait for a reply, the *server app* will receive the request message sent by the *client app*, process it, generate a reply message and send it to the *client app* (that was waiting for it). Now, what you want is for the *client app* to specify the `JMSExpiration` of the reply message that will be generated and sent by the *server app*, I'm I getting this right?

Comment: I want the `JMSExpiration` of the reply message to be set, but I'm indifferent to whether it's the *client app* or *server app* that actually sets it (I control both, so I can configure things on whichever side is necessary), and I would expect that only the *server app* would be able to do so.

Comment: so, setting `timeToLive` URI option from the *server app* side should take care of this. Is there a reason why would you not prefer that?

Comment: You're right that the `timeToLive` URI option on the *server app* does exactly what I want.  I thought I had tested that and seen it not set the `JMSExpiration`, but I must have not tested it properly.  Thanks for taking the time to work through this (and get me to re-test that URI option).  If you edit your answer to point out that the `timeToLive` URI option does what I need (so future readers don't have to dig through these comments), I'll accept it and award the bounty.

Comment: glad things worked out for you, I updated my answer accordingly.